# Automatic Blog - Multiple PHP function declaration?

Tags: php, html

I want to generate HTML using PHP based on files in a specific Folder, everything works for the first File but if I add a second File, I just see:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getTitle() (previously declared in [path]:3) in [path].php on line 4

I understood the Problem but I don't know how to solve it. This is the PHP-Code of the main File:

```
foreach (glob("content/blog/*.php") as $file) {
    require_once $file;
    $index = str_replace("content/blog/", "", str_replace(".php", "", str_replace("img/", "", $file)));
                    ?>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3><?php getTitle() ?><span><?php getPublishedDate() ?></span></h3>
                        <p><?php getContent() ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        $file = null;
                        }
                    ?>
```

And this is the PHP-Code in every Blog-File:

```
 <?php
 function getTitle() {
      echo "Lorem Ipsum 2!";
 }

 function getPublishedDate() {
      echo "When Time has finally come";
 }

 function getContent() {
      echo "<p>Text</p>";
 }
 ?>
```

I searched for opposites of include, include_once, require or require_once. I also tried Setting the variable back to null before foreach is called again.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: To solve the problem you should declare a class "blogEntry" which has some methods (getTitle/setTitle,getPublishedDate/setPublishedDate,getContent/setContent) and instantiate one object of this class in each of your blog files. Then use the set* methods to set the actual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class to store the information about one blog post.

```
// name this file class.blogEntry.php

class blogEntry {
    var $title;
    var $publishedDate;
    var $content;

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getPublishedDate() {
        return $this->publishedDate;
    }

    public function setPublishedDate($date) {
        $this->publishedDate = $date;
    }

    public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent($content) {
        $this->content = $content;
    }   
}
```

For each blog post create a simple php file to set it's different properties

```
$entry->setTitle("Lorem Ipsum 2!");
$entry->setPublishedDate("When Time has finally come");
$entry->setContent("<p>Text</p>");
```

Modify your output to use the class and the class based blog entries

```
require_once 'class.blogEntry.php';
foreach (glob("content/blog/*.php") as $file) {
    $entry = new blogEntry();
    require_once $file;
    $index = str_replace("content/blog/", "", str_replace(".php", "", str_replace("img/", "", $file)));
?>
    <div class="content">
        <h3><?php $entry->getTitle() ?><span><?php $entry->getPublishedDate() ?></span></h3>
    <p><?php $entry->getContent() ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
    $file = null;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! PHP is more similar to JavaScript than I thoght until now

Comment: Even though php had a really "script kiddy" like start it has developed and gained real OOP features ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have several files, defining the same function `getTitle` and you are requiring them.

Requiring or including a `*.php` file is like merging all the code into one single file, which explains the error, because you are requiring n files and in each of them you are defining the same functions.

You can do something like this instead of functions you can use associative array.

```
<?php
// blog_file_1.php
$prop = array(
    'title' => "This is file 1!",
    'published_date' => "When Time has finally come",
    'content' => "<p>Text</p>"
);

<?php
// blog_file_2.php
$prop = array(
    'title' => "This is file 2!",
    'published_date' => "When Time has finally come",
    'content' => "<p>Text</p>"
);

<?php
// blog.php
foreach (glob("content/blog/*.php") as $file) {
    require_once $file;
    $index = str_replace("content/blog/", "", str_replace(".php", "", str_replace("img/", "", $file)));
                ?>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3><?php echo $prop['title'] ?><span><?php echo $prop['published_date'] ?></span></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $prop['content'] ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php
                    $file = null;
                    }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you but maybe it will help others that might find this question as it hits what I was looking for. I was looking to exactly this a few days ago and didn't find much for a simple PHP script to generate a blog. I put this together after searching Stack for different functions (Generate gallery with links from a folder, PHP Pagination, Passing Variable from Another PHP File, Sort Files) and put this together.

Code for the main blog page

```
    \\Blog.php
    <?php
    $directory = "blog/folder/";
    $blogfiles = glob($directory . "*.php");
    usort($blogfiles, function($file_1, $file_2)
    {
        $file_1 = filectime($file_1);
        $file_2 = filectime($file_2);
        if($file_1 == $file_2)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return $file_2 < $file_1 ? 1 : -1;
    });

    $post_count  = 5;
    $total_pages   = ceil(count($blogfiles)/$post_count);
    $page          = $_REQUEST['page']; ///make it dyanamic :: page num
    $offset        = ($page-1)*$post_count;
    $files_filter  = array_slice($blogfiles, $offset,$post_count);

    foreach ($files_filter as $blogfile) {
    ob_start();
    include "$blogfile";
    ob_end_clean();
    echo '<div class="blog-post"><a href="'.$blogfile.'"><img src="'.$BLOG_IMG.'"><h1 
    class="blog-title">' . $BLOG_TITLE . '</h1></a><br><p class="blog-summary">' . 
    $SUMMARY . '</p></div><hr>', "\n";
    }

    if($total_pages > 1){
    if($page > 1){
    echo '<div class="blog-pagination prev-page"><a href="blog.php?page='.($page- 
    1).'">Prev Page</a></div>';
    }

    if($page != $total_pages){
    echo '<div class="blog-pagination next-page"><a href="blog.php?page='. 
    ($page+1).'">Next Page</a><div class="blog-pagination">';
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Here is a blog post template

```
    \\post1.php
    <?php
    $DOC_TITLE = "Document Title for browser tab";
    $BLOG_TITLE = "Blog Post Title";
    $SUMMARY = "Page summary";
    $BLOG_IMG = "/Path/to/blog/image.jpg";
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php'; //Pre-made HTML header in the root folder - or just replace with HTML header
    ?>
    \\content
    <?php
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/footer.php'; //Pre-made HTML footer in the root folder - or just replace with HTML footer
    ?>
```